# Changing app homepage content daily

Tags: ios7

I am developing an iOS app for iPhone using Xcode of course, and need to have the facility to update the information on my initial view daily. This would consist of editing a logo for the day's date, and daily changing a block of text on the same page.

Another feature within the app would need to be to progressively add more and more content (adding further menus and categories of information available to the user on the interface).

I cannot seem to find anything to help me online so I would be HUGELY GRATEFUL for any help!

Cheers :)

Comment: I think this question is too broad for SO because any answer would be several pages long.

Answer (score 0):

Search for JSON and how to retrieve data from an online resource - that's what you want.
Here's a randon tutorial:
http://www.appcoda.com/fetch-parse-json-ios-programming-tutorial/

Comment: Okay cool, thanks very much! Do you think it might work if I use a WebView linked to a website? The content displayed is meant to be publicly available anyway, so do you guys think that this would work?

Comment: Sure you can. Maybe what you really need is an adaptive mobile website instead. Not everything has to be a native app.